# Retrieve coordinates from Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter, coordinates

I have a plotted a set of points and embedded the plot into Tkinter canvas. What I am trying to do is retrieve the coordinates when clicked on one / more points. I was able to do it using the following code (before embedding into Tkinter). However, it works for only the first plot in the iteration. How do I expand it for the next 2 plots? Can someone please explain the changes need to be done using a canvas?

```
outl=[]
index = []
list_rep = []
def on_pick(event):
        thisline = event.artist
        xdata, ydata = thisline.get_data()
        tmp = []

        index.append(i)
        ind = event.ind
        tmp.append(list(xdata[ind])[0])
        tmp.append(list(ydata[ind])[0])
        outl.append(tmp)


        #print('on pick line:', zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))

new_ydata1 = []
new_ydata2 = []
new_ydata3 = []
for i in range(3):
        root = Tk.Tk()
        root.wm_title("Embed in Tk")

        ydata1 = np.array(Max_Correct_1[i])
        ydata2 = np.array(Max_Correct_2[i])
        ydata3 = np.array(Max_Correct_3[i])

        Aveg=np.array(Avg[i])


        f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
        ax1 = f.add_subplot(111)

        ax1.axis([-9.5,-4.0,-10,105])
        ax1.plot(Log_Values_Array,ydata1,'o',picker=7)
        ax1.plot(Log_Values_Array,ydata2,'*',picker=7)
        ax1.plot(Log_Values_Array,ydata3,'^',picker=7)
        ax1.plot(Log_Values_Array,Aveg,'b--')

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)

        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)


        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',on_pick)




        print outl



        canvas.get_tk_widget().delete("all")
        outl=[]
        index = []
        Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was able to collect coordinates, but have another problem. Since I am running it in a loop, e.g. 3 plots, it picks the coords for plot onw, but not for the subsequent plots. Is there a clear / update missing somewhere? Thank you

Comment: is this using matplotlib? If so, you might want to add a tag for that, and/or add that information in the description. Also, you say it's complaining about a particular line but don't show what the complaint is. Can you show the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Bryan, I was able to get rid of the event error, but in the code below, when I iterate through the plots and pick points to do some calculations, it does so only for plot #1. For Plot 2 and 3 the pick_event doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have the code in the original post of mine.

Comment: You need to define "doesn't seem to work". That can mean many things: is it throwing an error? Is it working, but not doing what you expect? Are you certain it's being called? When asking for help you need to be a bit more specific than "it doesn't seem to work".

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is the coordinates of points in the plots when a user clicks on the points. They are collected as a list in the above code. With the current code however, it works for plot #1 and I have the coordinates of the points in outl. When I move to the next image and click on new points, the list remains empty. This is where the mistake is. The list should now contain the coordinates of the points from Plot #2. I am guessing that I am missing a clear figure? clear plot or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has something to do with the fact that you're trying to create more than one instance of `Tk` by using a loop, and trying to call `mainloop` on each one.  There should only be one `Tk` for a given application, and therefore only call `mainloop` on that single instance.

Create that root `Tk` instance *before* you get to the `for` loop.  Once inside the loop, use the `TopLevel` widget to create each plot window as a child of that root.  Once the loop has ended, call `mainloop` on the root.

Here's a *very* rough code outline that should work:

```
# Code before loop just as it is, except you create your root Tk instance here...
root = Tk.Tk()

# Now start the loop
for i in range(3):
    win = Tk.TopLevel(root)
    win.title(text="Embed in Tk")
    ...
    # The rest of your plot-building code goes here, with all new widgets
    # as children of the window "win"

# Now that the loop is finished, call mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Without access to your data (and the other modules you're using), it'll be hard to confirm that this will work for what you need, but it *should* do the trick.

To work even more effectively, you may want to think about building a class for each plot window (subclassing `TopLevel`), and then using the loop to create three instances, passing the appropriate data to each instance.  That way each plot's window and operations can be isolated.